# Process silent postback with JSP

Tags: jsp, postback

I have limited knowledge on silent postbacks and how to process them with JSP. My question is similar to this, but I'm missing some pieces:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1414717.aspx?Consume+silent+post+back

A third-party is set up to do a silent postback to a URL that we have specified (JSP page on Tomcat)

Until recent changes, I believe the third-party redirected back to our JSP page, and there were no issues. 
But now, they're doing a silent postback, and not redirecting the client back to our JSP page. And I'm not sure what to change so that it will process the silent postback.

Questions:

1.) Is it accurate that there doesn't need to be a redirect in a silent postback?

If there is no redirect back to our JSP page, then what exactly is happening when they do the silent postback to the URL?

2.) If the client is not being redirected back to our JSP page, how do I verify (how do I display, how do I test) what is getting posted back? In other words, since the client is not redirected to our JSP page, I can't do a println or ... how do I look at what is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Check postback in jsp

```
if (!"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()))
{
            response.getWriter().write("PostBack = False <Br>");
}

if ( "POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod()))
{
            response.getWriter().write("PostBack = True <Br>");
}
```